# Matching an element in a list of tuple and removing the tuple element of the list

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

```
recipes = [('Peanut Butter','200g salt','500g sugar'),('Chocolate Brownie', '500g flour')]

def remove_recipe(recipe_name,recipes):
    recipe_dict = dict(recipes)
    size = recipe_dict.get(recipe_name)
    if size is not None:
        recipe_dict.pop(recipe_name)
        updated_recipes = [(k, v) for k, v in recipe_dict.items()]
        return updated_recipes

    else:
        print("There is no such recipe.")
```

What do I want to achieve ?
Hi I am new to python and I am trying to remove an item from a list of tuples. I converted the recipes list to dictionary and using size to value of a specific key. Once the key is not None it will remove the item from the dictionary and convert it back to list.

Error Received :
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required

Comment: You could use `recipe_dict = {x[0]: x[1:] for x in recipes}` to create a dictionary where the value is the ingredients as a tuple, and `(k, *v)` to create a whole tuple for the list.

Comment: I am trying to create a function that removes a recipe in the recipe list. If recipe_name matches a recipe in the recipes list, it will remove the entire tuple that belongs to that recipe. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would say there is no need to convert to dictionary - assuming that the first element of tuple is the name of recipe - just use list comprehension and compare the sizes, :

```py
def remove_recipe(recipe_name,recipes):    
    res = [r for r in recipes if r[0] != recipe_name] # filter out by the recipe name
    
    if len(res) != len(recipes):
        print("Recipe removed.")
    else:
        print("There is no such recipe.")

    return res
```

Comment: Did you mean `==`? E.g. no recipes were filtered?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal as I understand the goal is to remove the recipe with passed name. So you need `!=`.

Comment: If a recipe got removed, the lengths are not equal, so the recipe _was_ present and got removed.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal yep, was updating the code

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is a structure with key:value pairs. So you can't convert this tuples to a dict because it has no idea what it's supposed to do. You don't actually need a dictionary for what you're trying to do.

```
recipes = [('Peanut Butter','200g salt','500g sugar'),('Chocolate Brownie', '500g flour')]

def remove_recipe(recipe_name,recipes):
    for recipe in recipes:
        if recipe_name in recipe:
            recipes.remove(recipe)
            print("Recipe removed.")
            break

    else:
        print("There is no such recipe.")
```

A dict could structure your recipe but you'd have to refactor your recipes:

```
{
    "name": 'Peanut Butter',
    "ingredients": ['200g salt', '500g sugar']
}
```